# `resched_curr` in does not reschedule the current task instantly

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduling

I am working on designing a custom linux scheduler for linux version 6.0.19. It is a version of rsdl scheduler.

Now, after the time quanta assigned for the current job expires, I need to call the scheduler, so that I can switch that task to a new task (context switch). For that, I do the following:

When the task's quanta reaches zero in the `task_tick_rsdl` hook function (implemented by me), I call the function `resched_curr`.

```c
static void task_tick_rsdl(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *curr, int queued)
{
    struct sched_rsdl_entity *rsdl;
    struct rsdl_rq *rsdl_rq;
    int *queue_quota;
    trace_printk("task_tick_rsdl\n");
    rsdl = &curr->rsdl;
    rsdl_rq = &rq->rsdl_rq;
    queue_quota = rsdl_rq->active->quota + rsdl_rq->curr_prio;

    update_curr(rsdl_rq);

    if (rsdl->quota && *queue_quota) {
        rsdl->quota--;
        *queue_quota = *queue_quota - 1;
    }

    printk("p = %d ; tq = %lld\n ; qq = %d; cur_prio = %d", curr->pid,
           rsdl->quota, *queue_quota, rsdl_rq->curr_prio);

    if (!(rsdl->quota > 0 && *queue_quota > 0)) {
        resched_curr(rq);
        printk("need resched\n");
    }
}
```

The issue is that even after asking for reschedule, it is taking few more clock ticks to finally trigger the schedule.

The situation I encounter is as follows:

```
[   71.561489] picked task : pid = 170, quota = 0
[   71.561489] , prev = 36, cur = 36
[   71.561503] p = 170 ; tq = 0
[   71.561503]  ; qq = 5; cur_prio = 36
[   71.562085] need reached                  <-----------scheduler should have been called after this
[   71.562811] p = 170 ; tq = 0
[   71.562811]  ; qq = 5; cur_prio = 36
[   71.562812] need resched
[   71.563502] p = 170 ; tq = 0
[   71.563502]  ; qq = 5; cur_prio = 36
[   71.563503] need resched
[   71.564207] p = 170 ; tq = 0
[   71.564207]  ; qq = 5; cur_prio = 36
[   71.564208] need resched
[   71.564899] setting flag 1                <-----------scheduler actually called
[   71.565108] curr_prio = 36
[   71.565320] picked task : pid = 166, quota = 5
[   71.565320] , prev = 36, cur = 36
```

Please can you guide me so that this issue is resolved?

Comment: `resched_curr` does **not** immediately switch task. It simply sets `TIF_NEED_RESCHED` on the current task of the given runqueue. The scheduler will be invoked later on, so you can lose a tick. The difference between 71.564899 and 71.562085 is almost 5ms. If you have `HZ` equal to `100` on your system then that is well within a single tick (10ms).

Comment: "*I need to call ... I can switch ... I call the function ...*" -- Instead of referring to yourself when you are not describing what you, a human, is doing, specify the actual task or routine. If your workload expands to anything beyond one small routine, what "*I*" refers to starts to become ambiguous.